# Give a unit vector perpendicular to vector $v=2i+3j$.

Tags: vectors

Solution is "multiples of $3i-2j$". How is this answer reached?

Comment: Hint: draw what you're trying to do on a grid and it might become a bit more obvious.

Comment: easy ... $k$. Oh you mean in 2D ?!  Please edit the question to indicate so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $u = xi +yj \perp yi -xj$. You can take $v = \dfrac{yi-xj}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$, and use $x = 2$, and $y = 3$. Then: $u \perp v$, and $||v|| = 1$

Comment: The answer Dark-Chocolate gave is one way to do it, but also remember that two vectors are perpendicular if their dot product is zero. In this case, the dot product is zero. Also, for a vector $<a,b>$, $<-b,a>$ is perpendicular by the rule.